# netstat, listing connections correctly

Tags: linux, routing, netstat, firewalld

I have 2 machines

```
A 192.168.0.40 (CentOS)
B 192.168.0.41 (Debian)

Gateway 192.168.0.2
```

Now I did set a port forwarding using ***firewallD***, from

```
A port 2245 
to 
B port 22
```

Connection established from client 192.168.0.1 to Machine B trough Machine A

Running netstat on machine A

```
# netstat -tulpane
```

output:

```
# netstat -tulpane
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          16330      1/systemd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          20510      1273/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          21452      1841/master
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.40:22         192.168.0.1:64870       ESTABLISHED 0          142436     4598/sshd: root@
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.40:22         192.168.0.1:59846       ESTABLISHED 0          22169      2480/sshd: root
tcp        0     64 192.168.0.40:22         192.168.0.1:65139       ESTABLISHED 0          146378     4782/sshd: root@
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.40:22         192.168.0.1:65095       ESTABLISHED 0          145904     4756/sshd: root@
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.40:22         192.168.0.1:65024       ESTABLISHED 0          145298     4704/sshd: root@
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          16329      1/systemd
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          20519      1273/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          21453      1841/master
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           997        16978      782/chronyd
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:922             0.0.0.0:*                           0          41344      2868/rpcbind
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           0          41343      2868/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                997        16979      782/chronyd
udp6       0      0 :::922                  :::*                                0          41346      2868/rpcbind
udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                0          41345      2868/rpcbind
```

**Question:** Why I can't see the Machine B in connections ? and what shall I do to see it ?

Comment: What are you using to route the traffic from machine A to B? If you are using `iptables` to route the traffic, have a look at `masuqerade`. This `masquerade` rule has to be configured on machine B.

Comment: I'm using `firewallD` as stated in description, its interface on top of the `iptables`, masquerade is enabled, but how exactly shall I have to look in it and why exactly `netstat` can't see it , when there is clearly an established connection?

Comment: As a side note, netstat is deprecated by `ss` so I would start using `ss` (socket statisticks). On machine A you seen only incoming connections. iptables have conntracking tools to show that. Use tcpdump or anything more sophisticated to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why I can't see the Machine B in connections?

because it's acting as a router, not an endpoint of the connection.

> and what shall I do to see it?

To show connections tracked by the stateful firewall, run `conntrack`.

http://conntrack-tools.netfilter.org/manual.html#conntrack

If you did not have a stateful firewall, you would have to simply capture and interpret packets.  `wireshark` works well.